# Php different function headers

Tags: php

In php, what is the difference between:

```
 public function try($myArray)
```

and

```
 public function try(array $myArray)
```

Comment: This is type hinting, you can read more here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: A little off topic, but `try` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: removed salutation: "Thanks in advance.", don't do it next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function try($myArray)
```

`$myArray` can be any data type (i.e : `string`, `int` etc)

```
public function try(array $myArray)
```

`$myArray` can only be of type `array`

Answer (score 1):

well `public function try($myArray)` will accept arbitrary data type
while `public function try(array $myArray)` will accept array